# Is the index_db method from the SeqIO object in Biopython slow?

Tags: python, biopython

I've got this:

```
files = glob.glob(str(dir_path) + "*.fa")
index = SeqIO.index_db(index_filename, files, "fasta")

seq = index[accession] # Slow
index.close()

return seq
```

and i'm working on big files (gene sequences) but for some reasons, it takes about 4 secondes to get the sequence I'm looking for. I'm wondering if the index_db method is suppose to be that slow? Am I using the right method?

Thanks.

Comment: The right method for what? If you are only using the 'index_db' to get a single sequence you're not using it right.

Comment: @xbello Sorry, my bad. The right method for indexing sequences files. I have about 25 files each representing a gene and I must get a certain location in the sequence of a certain file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time the database is created it can take some time. The next times, if you don't delete the `index_filename` created, it should go faster.

Lets say you have your 25 files each with some genes. This method creates a SQLite DB that helps locating the sequences among the files, like "Get me the gene XXX" and the SQLite/index_db *knows* that the gene is in the file `12.fasta` and its exact location inside the file. So Biopython opens the file and scans quickly to the gene position.

Without that index_db you have to load every Records into memory, which is fast but some files might not fit in the RAM.

---

If you want speed to fetch regions you can use [FastaFile from pysam](http://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fasta#fasta-files) and [samtools](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools.html). Like this:

1. You have to index all the fasta files with `faidx`:

   ```
   $ samtools faidx big_fasta.fas
   ```
2. From your code write something like this:

   ```
   from pysam import FastaFile

   rec = FastaFile("big_fasta.fas")  # big_fasta.fas.fai must exist.
   seq = rec.fetch(reference=gene_name, start=1000, end= 1200)

   print(s)
   ```

In my computer this times 2 orders of magnitude faster than Biopython for the same operation, but you only get the pure sequence of bases.

Comment: That's what I though. But, is 4 seconds normal for fetching the sequence in the index like this:
    seq = index[accession] # Slow

Comment: The 4 seconds are not nor fetching (probably) but for: 1) build the DB, 2) index it, 3) query it 4) open the fasta file. How big are your files?

Comment: I looked and found out that the execution of the line "seq = index[accession] # Slow" is about 4 seconds. I guess opening the fasta must be long. The files are ranging between ~15K and ~250M

Comment: Try to open the largest file and searching for one gene, with `records = list(SeqIO.parse("Fasta.fas", "fasta"))`, and then `print(records[gene_name])`.

Comment: It took about 7 seconds to open. And the records list has only one record in it, the files represent 1 sequence each

Comment: Updated the original answer.

Comment: In your case, I would guess the indexing part of this is very fast - the slowness is likely after Biopython has opened the relevant file and jumped to the record (here no needed as there is only one record per file), because your sequence is so large that takes a noticeably long time just to parse into a massive single SeqRecord object.  Still, 4 seconds is a little surprising. Is this a public dataset?